# Import IIS Application (With WebDeployPackage) programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8, servermanager

I'm creating an MVC Application installer and I need to update a given application with packages that my company gives.

I already tried to use ServerManager class from *System.Web.Administration*, but it seems that this class doesn't contain any method that allow me to update applications.

Is there any way to do this programmatically? Or do i need to use MSDeploy cmd?

Comment: There is no public API to do so in code.

Comment: @LexLi oh, that's bad... :(

Comment: but why cannot you use command line of Web Deploy?

Comment: @LexLi, i can and i already did it, but i was thinking if there isn't another way of doing it. Thank you